# What are your most useful textexpander (or similar) snippets?

Tags: macos, productivity, textexpander

[TextExpander](http://www.smileonmymac.com/TextExpander/) is a program that aims to save you time by auto-replacing snippets of text with the content of your choice, or to quote their Web site:
*"Save yourself time and effort by typing short abbreviations for frequently-used text and images."*

So for instance when you type ,h1 it will change it to `<h1></h1>` with the cursor placed between the ><.

After some searching I have yet to find a resource/forum-thread/whatnot that discuss the uses of this marvelous program.

I am therefore looking for your best snippets or a link to a resource where I can find this.

Oh and one thing I can think of right away is `sigw, sigp` for my work/personal email signature.

Answer (score 1):

I use snippets in Textmate for most of the command line work that is repetitive.

Most of the time I use TextExpander for command line shortcuts that way I don't need aliases on every server that I work on.